# How to require google api client

Tags: google-api-client, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.4

I am using `google-api-client` gem for creating events in Google Calendar.

I found docs from google: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby

So, when I installed gem, after command `rails console` I tried require libs:

```
require 'google/api_client', 
require 'google/apis',
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
```

On each `require` I get
the error: `LoadError: cannot load such file`

Gem Info:

```
bundle info google-api-client

google-api-client (0.23.4)
Summary: Client for accessing Google APIs
Homepage: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client
Path: /Users/danielsaifulin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0-rc1@sortd/gems/google-api-client-0.23.4`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but in `rails console` when I call require 'google/apis' - it's don't work, but  when I run in some function in rails helper it's work.

So, question is closed.